# Presence of files in Recent Files that I did not open

Tags: files

Often when I open Places -> Recent Files, some random files I haven't opened in days (or even years) all of sudden appear there. If I check the File as Properties -> Last Accessed, it appears indeed that the file was open, often at a time while I was doing something at the computer (which had nothing do to with such file) or I was not even at the computer (idle status).
Should I call an exorcist?

Time frame: I noticed it the first time a month or two ago.

Version: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-2328M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4

Graphic: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2

Comment: What sort of files are showing up?  Are they personal files you have lingering on your hard drive (which might have been opened accidentally by you or someone with access to your machine) or are they system files that are being put in the Recent Files listings for reasons that might indicate a problem that needs to be fixed?

Comment: No system  files. Personal files such as music, photos, bills, etc. I'm 110% confident I did not open these files, and I'm the only person with access to this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above (2 at the time of this writing), unless someone comes back with a more definitive answer of what could be causing this issue, I'd be tempted to say either:

1) A rogue process is opening files - in which case an exorcism might be useful

2) User error - in your case opening files without thinking about it and then closing them (possible memory loss caused by being distracted by something else at the time).

3) OS bug - Recent documents are getting populated somehow, and I'm uncertain how this could be happening, especially in a LTS environment.

As the only one of these options includes a possible fix, monitor the issue and keep in touch!  If anyone has a better answer than this, aside from copying all personal files off this machine and doing a full system reinstall in a blind attempt to (calling in the exorcist) deal with possible issue #1 --- you could do that, but I don't see it as being an effective fix, personally --- please post an answer below.